# How to I filter out emails from multiple senders on a given date using imaplib in Python?

Tags: python, email, python-3.x, imap, imaplib

I am using the imaplib4 search function as of now and calling it multiple times for each email id. I tried looking everywhere on the internet to look for a format that would let me specify email ids in OR and a date.

As of now this format is working for me but I can only specify one email at a time so I make a call per email id.

```
(FROM "abc@email.com" (ON "25-Dec-2015"))
```

In case I have abc and def both sending me emails on that date, I would like a way to specify it in one call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server is RFC compliant and has a full search implementation you can chain together ORs.  A simple search should look something like

```
ON "25-DEC-2015" OR FROM "abc@email.com" FROM "def@email.com"
```

OR takes two search predicates.  If you need to chain them, embed an OR in the other one:

```
ON "25-DEC-2015" OR FROM "abc@email.com" OR FROM "def@email.com" FROM "ghi@email.com"
```

Not a very nice syntax, and it probably won't work beyond a handful of addresses.  Probably won't work on 'off-brand' IMAP servers.

Comment: its gmail btw. Thanks.

Comment: You can also use Gmail search syntax through their imap extensions, then.

Comment: Although it's gmail, I don't want to make the code specific to Gmail.

Comment: if syntax not very nice try this: consider each FROM is n. n-1 times insert OR before all FROMs like this: `ON "25-DEC-2015" OR OR FROM "abc@email.com" FROM "def@email.com" FROM "ghi@email.com"`